# Facebook share button is not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I currently use the sharer php approach to implement the share button in IE8. The problem is even the code is the same but the link generated in IE8 or other browser are different

**The code is** :

```
    // Change the information in FaceBook share
    function fbs_click() {
        u=location.href;
        t=document.title;
        window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=" + u + "&p[images][0]=http://www.hkheadline.com/image/logo_140.gif&p[title]=" + t + "&p[summary]= share message",'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');

        return false;
    }  



IE 8 :
http://www.facebook.com/issue/20121220/page/69&p[images][0]=http://www.hkheadline.com/image/logo_140.gif&p[title]=FlipBook%20demo&p[summary]=share message

Chrome / Fx :
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2F203.80.1.28%2FFlippingBook%2FDev%2FFrontend%2FflipV5.html%3Fissue%3D20121220&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hkheadline.com%2Fimage%2Flogo_140.gif&p%5Btitle%5D=FlipBook+Demo&p%5Bsummary%5D=%E9%A0%AD%E6%A2%9D%E6%97%A5%E5%A0%B1%E5%88%86%E4%BA%AB&page=1
```

Why different browser behave different and how to fix that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use %20 to represent # , that's all.